# Why could GC time increase in Kafka brokers with constant number of records, producers and consumers?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, garbage-collection

I use Kafka 2.1.0.

We have a Kafka cluster with 5 brokers (r5.xlarge machines). We often observe that the GC timings increase too much without any change in the rate of incoming messages severely impacting the performance of the cluster. Now, I don't understand what could be causing much sudden increase in GC time.

I have tried a few things with little improvement but I don't really understand the reason behind them.

```
export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx10G -Xms1G"
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"
```

I would like to understand the most important parameters when tuning GC in a Kafka broker.
Seeing the configuration above, where am I going wrong? What can be done to rectify this?

All the producers and consumers are working fine, and the rate of incoming messages remains fairly constant. Till now, we have not been able to figure out any pattern behind the sudden increase in GC times, it seems random.

**UPDATE**

After some further analysis, It turns out there was indeed some increase in the amount of data per sec. One of the topics had increased message input from around 10 KBps to 200 KBps. But I believed that Kafka could easily handle this much of data.

Is there something I am missing??

Grafana Snapshot
[image]

Comment: Is the size of the records the same all the time? Does the increase happen across all the brokers?

Comment: yes, there was indeed some increase in the amount of data being pushed into kafka. 

Interestingly No, Only 2-3 of these brokers see this significant increase even though all the topics are evenly spread across all brokers. 

Image added in the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by looking to see if the problem is *something else* than a GC tuning issue.  Here are a couple of possibilities:

- A hard memory leak will cause GC times to increase.  The work done by a GC is *dominated* by tracing and copying of reachable objects.  If you have a leak, then more and more objects will be (incorrectly) reachable.
- A cache that that is keeping too many objects reachable will also increase GC times.
- Excessive use of Reference types, finalizers, etc may increase GC times.

I would enable GC logging, and look for patterns in memory and space utilization reported by the GC.  If you suspect a memory leak because memory utilization is trending higher in the long term, go to the next step and use a memory profile to track down the leak.

Either way, it is important to understand what is causing the problem before trying to fix it.

---

> After some further analysis, it turns out there was indeed some increase in the amount of data per sec. One of the topics had increased message input from around 10 KBps to 200 KBps. But I believed that Kafka could easily handle this much of data.

It most likely can.  However, a 20x increase in throughput will inevitably lead to more objects being created and discarded ... and the GC will need to run more often to deal with this.

---

> How come just 200 Kbps of data divided among 5 brokers was able to break GC.

What makes you think that you have "broken" the GC?   15% time in GC doesn't mean it is broken.

Now, I can imagine that the GC may have difficulty meeting your 20ms max pause time goal, and may be triggering occasional full GCs as a result.  Your pause time goal is "ambitious", especially if the heap may grow to 10GB.   I would suggest reducing the heap size, increasing the pause time goal, and/or increasing the number of physical cores available to the JVM(s).

> By breaking I mean an increased delay in committing offsets and other producer and consumer offsets.

So ... you are just concerned that a 20 x increase in load has resulted in the GC using up to 15% of available CPU.  Well that's NOT broken.  That is (IMO) expected.  The garbage collector is not magic.  It needs to use CPU time to do its work.  The more work it has to do, the more CPU it needs to use to do it.  If your application's workload involves a lot of object allocation, then the GC has to deal with that.

In addition to the tuning ideas above, I suspect that you should set the `G1HeapRegionSize` size a lot smaller.   According to ["Garbage First Garbage Collector Tuning"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html) by Monica Beckwith, the default is to have 2048 regions based on the minimum heap size.  But your setting will give 1G / 16M == 64 initial regions.

Finally, if your *overall* goal is to reduce the CPU utilization of the GC, then you should be using the Throughput GC, not G1GC.  This will minimize GC overheads.  The downside is that GC pause minimization is no longer a goal, so occasional lengthy pauses are to be expected.

And if you plan to stay with G1GC, it is advisable to use the latest version of Java; i.e. Java 11.  (See ["G1 Garbage Collector is mature in Java 9, finally"](http://blog.mgm-tp.com/2018/01/g1-mature-in-java9/))

Comment: By breaking I mean an increased delay in committing offsets and other producer and consumer offsets. 
I will surely try to edits to settings. 

export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx4G -Xms2G"
export KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80"

I don't know much about these parameters. I will be trying the above settings.   Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. 
I am sorry I have zero knowledge when it comes to tuning GC. I just copied these settings off the internet when things weren't working as per our needs.

I will surely get a better understanding of GC as soon as time permits.

What value do you propose for G1HeapRegionSize?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka 2.1 uses G1GC by default, so I guess you can omit that argument. I'm assuming you're not using JDK 11. Compared to previous versions, JDK 11 brings significant improvement to G1GC. Instead of running a single-threaded full GC cycle, it can now achieve parallel processing. Even though that shouldn't improve the best case scenarios by a big margin, but worst case scenarios should see significant improvement. If possible, please share your results after migrating to JDK 11.

**Note**: I doubt that's the root cause, but let's see.

Comment: I doubt that would solve the real problem. Upgrading the java version may improve GC but I doubt it'll solve the actual problem causing the issue.